# Getting a part of a string in PHP

Tags: php

Having the following string:

```
"[{"name":null,"value":"","target":null,"alias":"","required":1,"showNull":0}]"
```

How can I get the `1` from the `required` part? I need just the `1`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not parse the json? or isn't it always valid?

Comment: First of all your string is not valid. If you have valid string you can try json_decode(), after that you can get with required key.

Comment: @VaheGalstyan The string is valid JSON... https://eval.in/739285

Comment: @BenM  please check string in your example and string in question, your string start with ' , but in question it start with " .

Comment: @VaheGalstyan The actual content of the string itself is valid JSON. Indeed, the example the OP has added is not a valid string in PHP, but I assumed it was a demonstration.

Comment: @BenM question about php, it's a reason why I said that ). Without that I Accept your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the string will always be JSON, use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$array = json_decode('[{"name":null,"value":"","target":null,"alias":"","required":1,"showNull":0}]');
```

Now you can access the `required` option as follows:

```
$array[0]->required;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
<?php
$string = '[{"name":null,"value":"","target":null,"alias":"","required":1,"showNull":0}]';
$string_array = json_decode($string, true);
echo $string_array[0]['required'];
?>
```

Comment: Please upvote answers already posted, rather than duplicating them :)

Comment: @BenM different answers!

Comment: Not really. You just passed in the `associative` option to `json_decode()`!

Comment: @BenM: it seems that you proud of json_encode? play with your pet dudy.

Answer (score 0):

In single line, using the functions [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [current](http://php.net/current):

```
$str = '[{"name":null,"value":"","target":null,"alias":"","required":1,"showNull":0}]';
$required = current(json_decode($str))->required;
```